# Where is the "Open in Low Resolution" setting stored for an app?

Tags: display, resolution, ui

I'd like to script the opening of an app - which is normally used in retina resolution - to open in low resolution.

1. set low resolution setting
2. open app
3. clear low resolution setting

But where is the "Open in Low Resolution" setting stored for an app?

It seems different macOS store it in different places. I'm using Mojave.

[image]

Comment: Surely on a Retina screen, the app's UI will look blotchy and low-res if you do this? Why do you want to do this? Is another method for achieving the end goal?

Comment: The app has a bug exporting images in retina mode, but I still want to use retina mode when I'm not exporting (which is most of the time). I'd rather not have to check and uncheck the get info box so I'd prefer a way to launch the app in either mode. Also, fwiw, it's exhausting to have to justify questions in the comments.

Comment: Oh, and the app is written using Qt framework so the UI is low resolution even in retina mode.

Comment: By providing more background info, you can get the best answers. FWIW, there's nothing about Qt that demands low-res UI. There are plenty of Qt apps that work fine on Retina displays.

Comment: Sure, but I'm talking about this specific one. It is what it is - it has problems. I didn't write it, I just use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Where is the “Open in Low Resolution” setting stored for an app?

When checking/unchecking the **Open in Low Resolution** checkbox on an *App's* **Get Info** *window* in **Finder**, an entry is created/modified under **LSHighResolutionModeIsMagnified** in the following *file*:

```
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices/com.apple.LaunchServices.plist
```

In the image below, **Item 1** showing a *value* of **3** is when checked, and **2** when unchecked.

[image]

**Update to address comment.**

From **Terminal**:

```
$ defaults read ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices/com.apple.LaunchServices.plist 
{
    LSHighResolutionModeIsMagnified =     {
        "com.adobe.adobeconnect.app" =         (
            <626f6f6b ...>,
            3
        );
    };
}
$
```

Note in the above output that the *value* of the first item of the *array* is truncated to `<626f6f6b ...>` for brevity.

Also note the difference in how **Xcode** displays the contents of the **PLIST** *file* verses the `defaults` *command* in **Terminal**.

If using the **PlistEdit Pro** *application*, it will show the *elements* of an *array* with just a *numerical value* as its *label* while omitting the *word* **item**.

[image]

In either case using a **GUI** both *labels* are *virtual* and do not exist in the actual *data structure* of the *array*. Only the output of the `defaults` *command* represents an accurate *data structure* of the *data* itself.

---

<sub>Tested on **macOS High Sierra**.</sub>

Comment: Interestingly, this is not the case on Mojave. The search continues!

Comment: I take that back, it's there if I use Xcode to view the plist but not if I use PlistEditPro!

Comment: Thanks for the update, interestingly your PlistEditPro displays the file completely differently than mine: https://i.imgur.com/tq2d4jW.png

Comment: Do you think this has changed for Monterey? I’m trying to get VirtualBoxVM to open in low resolution mode, but changing it here doesn’t work for me. It certainly works if I change the High Resolution Capable property in `Info.plist` to NO.

Comment: For others reading this: On macOS Monterey, I tried setting High Resolution Capable to NO in ZBrush's `Info.plist` (version 2021.7), but without any effect. Updating `com.apple.LaunchServices.plist` didn't have any effect either.